# Generate a link that uses html in a table column to create a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a program where I need to create a link which will open a page and display html tags stored in a table column. I tried passing it into the url of a html page and then parsing it but that didn't work (Not all of the html got passed in). How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you are saying that you are passing HTML tags in the URL, is it so?
If that's the case than you will have to keep in mind that there is a limit of URL length and you will loose data.
If I have understood it wrong, kindly elaborate and provide some code.

Comment: That is correct, the string was too long and was getting truncated. I had to create another page and pass a reference to the database and query the correct data and then display it